# Implement a recursive function in int main() [c++]

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I am using a recursive floodfill function in my program. The program is given below

```
void floodfill(int x, int y, int &array[100][100])
{
 if (array[x][y]==0)
  {
   array[x][y]=1;
   floodfill(x+1, y, array);
   floodfill(x, y+1, array);
   floodfill(x-1, y, array);
   floodfill(x, y-1, array);
  }
}

int main()
{
   int x= 1;// x and y is the point to start the floodfill
   int y= 10;
   int array[100][100] = {0};

   floodfill(x, y, array); 
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to program this recursive function to happen completely inside the int main loop without creating a function?

PS:- I am aware that it is good programming practice to define a function and then use it in the main program, but the architecture of the project I am working on does not enable me to do floodfill using function. hence I want the complete floodfill program in the int main section.Also this is not the complete code. the part where the values of the array get initialized are not provided in the code.

Comment: this code can't complie,`int &array[100][100]` is an array of refernces. for a reference to an array write `int (&array)[100][100]`

Comment: @ Tyker this is not the complete code. I just put in the bits that help explain the question.

Comment: You can implement the same floodfill without recursion by using priority queue. You can look at Dijkstra's alghorithm for reference.

Comment: Can you tag this as C instead of C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFS can be implemented without recursion using stack only, so u might want to see this:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/723337/Depth-First-Search-DFS-Non-recursive

this code is implemented for the tree, but the algorithm is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

You need to pass parameters to make your code work. Main takes no parameters.

And I then feel the need to ask why you would want to do that? It's good programming practice to break your code down to small, well defined parts, that carry out a specific task. And then you isolate that in a function, and you document/describe that function for everyone else to understand what it does.

So even if you could do that, you really should refrain from doing it.

Comment: My problem is that I cannot pass the array to the function in my program architecture.  To be precise the array is part of a struct and it is designed in such a way that every time the struct is passed to a function, its value gets written to a .h5 file. and I do not have the power in my work place to get the struct restructured just to serve my purpose.

Comment: @McMissile You can **always** pass a reference or pointer to this object

Comment: "Main takes no parameters." Ubs! My compiler is broken ;) Main takes parameters and you can call main yourself with this interface of `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. But you should never do that ;) So the idea is broken independent of what is technically is possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

Local non-static variables, including arrays like your `array`, are by default not initialized. Their values will be *indeterminate* and seem almost random.

Using such variables in any way, except to initialize them, leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

And that's what happens because you compare a value in your array without it being initialized.

Furthermore, and also a source of *undefined behavior*, you have no bounds-checking! That means your function can (and will) go out of bounds of your array.

---

To solve the first problem you need to initialize your array:

```
int array[100][100] = { 0 };  // Set all elements to zero
```

To solve the second problem you need to add bounds-checking in your function:

```
if (x < 0 || x >= 100 || y < 0 || y >= 100)
    return;
```

Comment: This is not the complete code. the part where the values of the array get initialized are not provided in the code

Comment: @McMissile How would we then be able to correctly help you? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should not only be minimal, but also complete and verifiable.

Comment: The values in the array get assigned after a some other calculations(too big to be provided here)